# VSTS Manual Test Fails, Bug Created, What is the Retest Trigger?

Tags: azure-devops, manual-testing

Puzzling out how to implement VSTS for testing team. 
Regarding the scenario where a manual test is run and a bug is created...
The bug gets prioritized and fixed at some later point.
How does the application indicate to the tester when they can run the test again because the bug has been fixed?

Answer (score 0):

When you run the tests each time it has its own `test run ID`.  That means they will have their own test results even if you run the same test case multiple times (They have different test run IDs).

Generally, once the bug is fixed and the fixed sources are integrated into the next release of the application, then you can run the test again to check if the bug is really fixed or not.

More information about the manual tests please see [Run manual tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/test/run-manual-tests?view=vsts) and [FAQs for manual testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/test/reference-qa?view=vsts#qanda)

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I've poured through the links and more stuff like ALM Rangers guidance and just can't find this answer.  I understand that the test can be run again, but how does the user identify that it is time to run the test again?

Maybe this background is important.  We aren't fully agile. Smoke testing happens during development in a sprint but not complete functional testing.  For reasons, that aren't in my control, going full agile is not an option.  The tools for testing look great, but I can't figure how we will manage when to retest items.

Comment: @BethDagle Basically you need to retest once something changes related to the feature/component. In general it will have release notes or debug comments with the project developing goes. The user/manager can capture the change information from the notes/comments and identify if you need to retest the corresponding feature/component.